# Where is uploaded data stored in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm uploading a form to an Express.js server, just trying to parse it correctly. I can print what has been parsed to console. I'm not saving it anywhere, where is the uploaded data stored? If it's cache, do I need to clear it manually?

Answer (score 1):

It (form) will be stored in request object and request object will in memory.

you don't have to clear explicitly it

> [V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/) is responsible for clearing unreachable objects in node

If you interested in `how garbage collection works`, you can check out
following links

> [Getting garbage collection for free](https://v8project.blogspot.in/2015/08/getting-garbage-collection-for-free.html)
>
> [Generational garbage collection](https://v8project.blogspot.in/2017/11/orinoco-parallel-scavenger.html)
>
> [Garbage collection in v8](https://medium.com/@_lrlna/garbage-collection-in-v8-an-illustrated-guide-d24a952ee3b8)

Comment: Thanks! The same goes for files?